# If $\pi$ is a representation of a lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, why is $\pi(x)$ not required to be invertible?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, definition, lie-algebras, motivation

The definition of a representation of a group $G$ is a homomorphism $\pi: G\to GL(V)$. So here $\pi(x)$ is an invertible linear map $V \to V$.

The definition of a representation of a lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is a homomorphism $\pi: \mathfrak{g} \to End(V)$. So here $\pi(x)$ is just a linear map.

**What is the motivation for not requiring invertibility? Is this something with category theory?**

Comment: The Lie algebra of $GL_n(K)$ is $\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)$ consisting of *all* $n\times n$-matrices, not necessarily invertible. It is a vector space. In a group, every element must be invertible, but not in a vector space of matrices.

Comment: Or in yet other words: A representation is, among other things, a map that preserves certain structural properties. An important structural property of group elements is that they are all invertible. For Lie algebra, there is no "multipicative" structure w.r.t. which all elements are invertible (in fact, the map $[x, \cdot]$ is *never* invertible). Rather, the "correct" invertible structure on a LA is the *additive* one, and you'll find indeed that for any $\pi(x)$ also $-\pi(x)$ is in the representation. Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4343929/96384

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then what would $\pi(0)$ be? Since $\pi$ is a Lie algebra homomorphism, in particular it is a linear map, and therefore $\pi(0)=0$. And the null map is not invertible.

Besides, if $X\in\mathfrak g$, then the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}\operatorname{ad}(X)\colon&\mathfrak g&\longrightarrow&\mathfrak g\\&Y&\mapsto&[X,Y]\end{array}$$is *never* invertible (since $\operatorname{ad}(X)(X)=0$). But $\operatorname{ad}$ is the adjoint action, which is the natural action of $\mathfrak g$ on itself.

Comment: Couldn't $\pi(0)$ just be the identity matrix? So we would have a homomorphism from an additive thing to a multiplicative thing (group). EDIT: ... Oh maybe nevermind mind. I don't think I understand Lie algebra homomorphisms well enough...

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, then $\pi$ would not be a linear map.

Comment: Thank you for this. This helps clear it up.

Answer (score 2):

If $\pi: G \rightarrow \operatorname{GL}(V)$ is a representation of a Lie group $G$ on a finite dimensional vector space $V$, then the differential $d \pi: \mathfrak g \rightarrow \operatorname{End}(V)$ is a Lie algebra representation of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ into the space of all linear maps from $V$ to itself.

Originally, Lie algebra representations showed up as differentials (tangent space maps) from ordinary group representations, which are invertible.  These differentials are, in particular, linear maps.  They send $0$ to $0$, and therefore you are forced to deal with non-invertible elements of $\operatorname{End}(V)$.

Answer (score 2):

For a representation of a group you don’t need to require $π(g)$ to be invertible:
a representation of group $G$ is a pair $(V, π)$ consisting of a vector space $V$ and a homomorphism of monoids $π \colon G \to \operatorname{End}(V)$. More explicitly: the map $π$ needs to be multiplicative, so that $π(gh) = π(g)π(h)$ for any two elements $g$ and $h$ of $G$, and it needs to satisfy $π(1_G) = 1_{\operatorname{End}(V)}$.

However, it then turns out that $π(g)$ is actually invertible for every element $g$ of $G$.
This then allows us to regard $π$ not only as a homomorphism of monoids from $G$ to $\operatorname{End}(V)$, but also as a homomorphism of groups from $G$ to $\operatorname{GL}(V)$.
(Which is why most people don’t bother with $\operatorname{End}(V)$ and just use $\operatorname{GL}(V)$ to begin with.)

Comment: I hadn't thought about that. This is really good way to look at it.